# public bool var not updating its value

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a `public bool LogedIn;` in my **login.cs**:

```
if(login successful condition)
LogedIn = true;
else
LogedIn = false
```

But when I access this var from another form with `Login Log = new Login();`

by using `if(Log.LogedIn)` the `LogedIn` variable is always **false**, even after successful login by the user.

Why this is not working/updating its value outside its parent form?

Updating the code:
**Login.cs**

```
public bool isLogedIn;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (i>-1 && (textBox2.Text == DS.Tables[0].Rows[--i][0].ToString()))
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            isLogedIn = true;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid password supplied for username \"" + comboBox1.Text + "\"", "Login Error.....", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            isLogedIn = false;
            return;
        }
}
```

Checking for the updated value in **Home.cs**

```
        private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Log.isLogedIn)  // Always False at this position.
            {
                label18.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                submitButton.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                label18.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                submitButton.Enabled = false;
            }
}
```

I've checked again... I'm not having double instance of this variable in **Login.cs** form.

Here's how I'm calling Login.cs form via Home.cs (main form). Hope this helps...

```
private void loginToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Log.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Log_FormClosed);
    Log.ShowDialog(this);
    Log.BringToFront();
}

void Log_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Log.isLogedIn)
    {
        // Something here
    }
    else
    {
        // Something here
        if (Log.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
            Log.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried debugging?

Comment: FYI, the past tense of log is logged with two Gs.

Comment: Please show more code. My guess is that you're creating two separate instances of `Login`, but we can't tell from what you've shown.

Comment: Are you creating a new instance of Login in **Another form**? If that is the case, how could you expect the value set in one instance on the other????

Comment: maybe `log in successful condition` is not so successful?

Comment: @BoltClock Just a doubt... Do u always use `spell checks` & `grammar` in ur variable names? I wonder what u might be getting outta doing such funny things while coding? Well my teacher never told me to use proper spellings in coding... so I keep using unique variable names... hope such spelling don't offend the coders community.

Comment: @gsvirdi That word is spelled "you".

Comment: You seem more offended than I am. (On the contrary, I'm not offended at all.)

Comment: In Home.cs file, are you creating a new instance of Login class? or is there any line as Login Log = new Login();

Comment: @ArunDhaj As per my updated code I am using `Login Log = new Login();` line so that I can use `if(Log.isLogedIn)` statement. I thought I can fetch the value if I keep the variabel as public.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a form called Login in your application. Ignore the rest if assumption is wrong.

You are not referring to the correct instance of the Login form. In windows application, there is a collection called `Application.OpenForms`. This contains all the open form instances in your application. To access the correct Login form, try this:

```
Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>().Where(x => x is Login).FirstOrDefault()
```

Make sure you have Login form always open to perform this task. You can make use of `Hide` instead of `Close` or `CloseDialog` for the Login form.

If you are closing the Login form, you can create static class which is accessible from each of the forms keep the properties there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have more than one instance of the Login class, each one with its isLogedIn var.

It is not clear where you are instantiating Login with your Login Log = new Login(); line. Have you tried to put a breakpoint there and see how many times it gets hit?

Another thing you could do is put a breakpoint on the line where isLogedIn is set, and another one where you read it. When the setting breakpoint is hit add a watch to the instance of Login (in this case add a watch to *this*) and choose Make Object ID from the right click menu. Your instance will be marjked by a "#1" Then do the same for the variable Log when the reading breakpoint is hit. If the mark is different (i.e. "#2") you can be sure that you are reading something different from the variable you set before.